# How to call/generate nyro modal pop up using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

hello friends i m new to jQuery and nyro modal.

right now i m using nyro modal pop up in this way:

```
<a href='#add_sub_user' class="nyroModal" >
<input type="button" name="a1" value="Add"  class="buttons" />
</a>
```

Now i want to call the same pop up using javascript like "to show hidden div we use

```
$("#sent_already").show();
```

Can any body tell me How can i call Nyro modal pop up using javascript..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for the problem:

```
<a href="#add_sub_user" id="popup_generate"  style="disply:none;" class="nyroModal"></a>
```

This a anchor tag.Fine. "add_sub_user" is the id of the Div which u want to display in the Nyro Modal.

Now 
call this to generate your pop-up from java script.

```
$('#popup_generate').nyroModalManual();
```

your "add_sub_user" div will be displayed.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just

```
$('#add_sub_user').nyroModal();
```